# Setting two equations equal to eachother

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I am trying to figure out how to solve for lambda. I'm pretty sure the issue with the following code is how I am defining lambda at the beginning but I am unsure how to fix it.

```
lambd = symbols('X')
first = S / (4*10^4)
second = (1- R)
total1 = 0
total2 = 0
for u in range(1, 3):
    Calc = math.exp((S/10000)*(u/4)) * (2.718**( -lambd * (u/4)))
    total1 = total1 + Calc
    eq1= first * total1 


    Cal = math.exp((S/10000) * (u/4)) * (2.718**(-lambd*((u-1)/4)))
                                             
    total2 = total2 + Cal
    eq2 = second * total2
    
print(eq1)
print(eq2)

return(solve((eq1,eq2)))
```

*Updated
The output i end up getting for the above code is empty brackets [], and I am unsure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: All of the functions in the `math` module perform actual computations with concrete numbers - they're completely inappropriate for use with a symbolic value, you need to use the corresponding functions from `sympy` (or whatever symbolic math package you're using).

Comment: Along with @jasonharper's comment, it looks like there's a typo in your equation in that you seem to be missing an operator (maybe a `+` or `-`) in `r1` before the final exp.

Comment: Rather than use `2.718**` you can do `from sympy import exp` and use `exp` instead. Also, I think you should use `solve(Eq(eq1,eq2), lambd)`. As you've found, sympy doesn't seem to be able to find a solution. Are you sure a valid analytical solution exists?